# Wait until music section is finished to start next one

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a 3d platformer with music playing in loops with different sections separated by a collider to play the next loop of the song, basically play 30 seconds of song and repeat if the player hasn't progressed to the checkpoint, but when the player passes the checkpoint, I want the next loop to play when the previous one has finished to create a nice transition from section to section.

I tried to have the colliders set the variable of music loop for the next collider after it and if the player got there too early, I played a tape stop, but realized that if you waited too long and went to the next collider it would cut off the previous music loop anyway, internalloop bit at the bottom is just so i can see in the Unity editor if the number had successfully changed

```
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       if (MusicLoop.loopEnd == 1)
       {
           StartCoroutine(MusicTiming());
           IEnumerator MusicTiming ()
           {
               loopStart.Play();
               MusicLoop.loopEnd = 2.5f;
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(loopDuration);
               MusicLoop.loopEnd = 3;
           }
           {
               loopEnd.Stop();
           }
       }
       if (MusicLoop.loopEnd == 0.5f)
       {
           StartCoroutine(MusicOffTiming());
           IEnumerator MusicOffTiming()
           {
               loopEnd.Stop();
               earlyStart.Play();
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
               MusicLoop.loopEnd = 2.5f;
               loopStart.Play();
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(loopDuration);
               MusicLoop.loopEnd = 3;
           }
       }


   }

   void Update()
   {
       internalloop = MusicLoop.loopEnd;
```

Answer (score 1):

So I would tackle the problem a bit different for transitions.

I would make a fade between the tracks while one increase the other decrease.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
  other.getcompoent<AudioController>().ShouldMakeTransition();
}


Void ShouldMakeTransition()
{
 // Use lean tweak or dot tween to make the fade.
audiosource1 - > Reduce Volume
audiosource2 - > Increase Volume
}
```

I would not use Enumerators in this case. Learn Tween will make your life much easier.